# How to apply custom CSS styles of Angular library within a host application?

Tags: css, angular, angular-library

I have built an Angular library containing a `styles.css` file with some custom CSS. When I include the library in a test application in the same repository it works fine:

```
library-repo/
├── projects/
│   ├── custom-library/
├── src/
│   ├── app/
│       ├── app.component.html
```

However, once I publish the library and import it in a separate application, the custom styles are not applied. How can I bundle the `styles.css` with the library so that the library components are styled consistently across all host application?

Answer (score 0):

Put the styles you want in the `styles` file at this path

```
/src/styles.scss
```

Comment: Do you mean add them to the the `/src` of the host project or the library?

Comment: There is a file under `/src` you should have it by default its called `styles.*` depending on what css or scss you are using

Comment: Do you the `/src/styles.css` of the host project or the library?

Comment: the project where your `package.json` is

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is portability, i.e. have the library carry its own styles. So that wherever I import it it looks the same. I can't force the client to change the styles of the host project.

Comment: put the external style sheet in `angular.json` file it will include it